# Eclipse Juno - unable to toggle breakpoint in an aspect file

Tags: eclipse, debugging, aspectj, eclipse-juno, ajdt

I just upgraded to Juno from Indigo SR2 and am having a little annoyance with the AJDT editor.

I'm unable to toggle a breakpoint in an AspectJ .aj file.  If I double click in the gutter or right click and select "toggle breakpoint" nothing happens.  I have to manually go to Run->Toggle Line Breakpoint to have the breakpoint added.  Similarly, to remove the breakpoint double clicking does not work - I have to use the breakpoint view or go to Run->Toggle Line Breakpoint to remove it.

I never had that issue in Indigo, so I am wondering if this is a problem with my Juno configuration or something in the AJDT.

Version information:

```
AJDT 2.2.1.e37x 
Eclipse 4.2.1.v20130118 (build M20130204)
```

I've also noticed that I don't get any code completion when editing aspect (.aj) files.  Even things as basic as

```
String x = "string"; 
x. (ctrl-space does nothing).
```

All my software is upgraded to the latest stable.

Is there anyway to fix this?  Could other plugins be causing conflicts?  If so, how would I figure out which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.  Had to uninstall the AJDT and the Spring Ide AJDT, and then update both Spring IDE AJDT and AJDT (via marketplace) and everything is working properly.  This may have been an issue from the Indigo->Juno upgrade I did within Eclipse.

Hopefully this can help someone else in the future.  One thing to note, the Spring IDE update site has changed for Juno to `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.2/`

Comment: Makes sense.  It looks like you had the e3.7 version installed into your e4.2 platform.